# Laravel Filament - how to make uploaded image only visible inside the filament admin panel

Tags: laravel, file-upload, local, laravel-filament

I have a filament form outside the admin panel where fotos can be uploaded. What do i have to do that the photos are not public visible, but only from INSIDE the Admin Panel?

If i put it to 'public' disk, the image  is accesible via  public url. And i can see it the filament admin panel.
If i put it to 'local' disk, the file is not appearing in the filament admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried uploading to a disk (you can create a separate one for these uploads) and setting the visibility to `private`?

```
FileUpload::make('attachment')
->disk('public')
->directory('form-attachments')
->visibility('private')
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it this way:

```
'disks' => [

        'private' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/private'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/private',
            'visibility' => 'private',
        ],
```

and

```
                        ->required()
                        //->panelLayout('integrated'),1
                        ->image()
                        ->minSize(20)
                        ->maxSize(4096)
                        ->label(__('Foto'))
                        //->preserveFilenames()->ojo macht probleme!
                        ->disk('private')
                        ->hint( __('Max. 4MB'))
                        ->directory('applicant-foto')
                        ->visibility('private')
                        ->columns(1)
                        //->panelAspectRatio('2:1')
                        ->imageResizeTargetWidth('1284'),
```

Comment: I have tried the above but I can't download the file after it has been uploaded.